# Implementing a method that gets an double array, and returns a new double array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
public class aufgabe1 {

    public static double[] mittelwert(double[] m){
        double mittelw =0;
        double[] neuesArray= new double[0];
        for (double i : m)
        {
            mittelw+=i;
            mittelw= mittelw/(double)m.length;
        }
        for(int i=1;i>m.length;i++){
            if (m[i]>mittelw){
                neuesArray[i]=m[i];
            }
        }
        return neuesArray;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double[]x={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

        for (double z : mittelwert(x))
        {
            {
                System.out.print(z + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

I need to implement a method that gets an double array, and returns a new double array which contains the values which are bigger than the average of the first arrays, i already tried it, but i am not sure how to get the output of the array to check if it works or not, since i don't even get an output with my current code.

Comment: Why do you think this line helps you calculate the average ? `mittelw/(double)m.length`

Comment: Because i calculate the sum of the Arrays values and Divide it By the amount of values of it

Comment: @R.You Do you need to perform this operation each time you loop over a value?

Comment: No, you are right, i'll put it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems here. The first is that you calculate the average incorrectly. You should only divide it by the total number of elements after you have calculated the total sum:

```
double mittelw = 0;
for (double i : m)
{
    mittelw+=i;
}
mittelw = mittelw / (double)m.length;
```

The next is that you're initialising the array to be zero elements long. 
You'll never be able to put anything in this. It has no elements.

```
double[] neuesArray = new double[0];
```

The difficulty here is what do we initialise it to? We don't know how many elements will be greater than average, and we can't change the size of an array after we've created it.

One solution is to initialise it to the same length as the input. You can use a for-each loop here, but we need to maintain a separate count of how many elements exceeded the average.

```
double[] neuesArray = new double[m.length];

int numOverAverage = 0;
for (double i : m)
{
    if (i > mittelw)
    {
        neuesArray[numOverAverage] = i;
        numOverAverage++;
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to trim the array to the correct size, otherwise the end of the array will still be filled with zeroes. You can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(double%5B%5D,int,int)) to accomplish this.

```
return Arrays.copyOfRange(neuesArray, 0, numOverAverage);
```

This means copy from index 0 to `numOverAverage` of `neuesArray` and return the new array.

You could alternatively create a third array and copy over the values once more, which is all that `copyOfRange` is going to be doing under the hood anyway.

---

[Runnable example](https://ideone.com/BgqVhZ)

Comment: THANKS A LOT,   the task was also to choose a viable return type. Do you think it is better to return an array when the input is an array, because i changed my code using an ArrayList? Since input=output?

Comment: @R.You `ArrayList` is more useful here because it will expand (and contract) dynamically. There's no need for step 3 (trimming the array). But you are also right that it makes sense to keep the input type and output type the same. By using `List` we make our lives easier, but maybe make the callers of our function's lives more difficult. By using `double[]` the reverse is true. Programming is all about trade-offs. There's rarely one objectively "best" solution. So use whichever you like. The only reason I didn't use an `ArrayList` was I didn't know whether you knew about them.

Comment: Thank you very much @Michael